# is there any alternative other than phonegap build for creating app in phone gap

Tags: cordova

I want to know if there is any alternative for building phone gap app other than phonegap build..so what is the approach for building phone gap app ..there is one alternative ac mobile app but it doent support all the devices .it only supports android,ios and windows. so plz let me know if there is any other alternative

Comment: You can use Cordova build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should check [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/)**

It's a complete software suite, which includes features such as layout live-editing, optimization tests, and simple debugging tools.

Hope it was what you were looking for. *It works wonders.*

Comment: ya it really works..but for building ios app we need mac right?

Comment: You only need a Mac to upload the app to the app store. Build and test all you want from a PC.

Comment: I just want to add that the Cloud compiler is depreciated as of June 2017.

Comment: Intel XDK is no more. Have a look at VoltBuilder (https://volt.build).